# Feynman rules for a toy theory

Tags: particle-physics, scattering, feynman-diagrams

For a process $A + A \rightarrow B + B$ scattering, Griffith says that the rules yield this integral

$$-i(2\pi)^4 g^2\int \frac{1}{q^2 - m^2_c c^2} \delta^4(p_1 - p_3 - q)\delta^4(p_2 + q -p_4)d^4q$$

so far so good. However, he also says that replacing $q$ with $p_4 - p_2$ and doing this integral we have

$$-i(2\pi)^4 g^2 \frac{1}{(p_4 - p_2)^2 - m^2_c c^2} \delta^4(p_1 + p_2 - p_3 - p_4)$$ (Introduction to elementary particles, second revised edition p.215)

I'm not sure how he did that. Is the second delta function $\delta(p_2 - p_2 + p_4 - p_4) = \delta(0) = \infty$ ?

Comment: You said: However, he also says that replacing q with p4−p2 and doing this integral we have.... This is wrong. What's actually happening is that when you do the integral over q, due to the second delta function, evaluating the integral is identical to removing the delta function and setting q such that the argument of that function vanishes i.e. $\int dq f(q) \delta(q-b) = f(b)$

Comment: Ah I see.  Thank you